# Access an element's object model in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is it possible to access an element's model from the element?

### Background

I'm trying to make a change to the way Ionic's [ion slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) work. There is a `Slides` component and a `Slide` component, and usage is like this:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide> Slide 1 </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide> Slide 2 </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Each `Slide` requires a reference to it's parent `Slides`. It's implemented like this:

```
export var Slide = (function () {
    function Slide(elementRef, slides) {
        this.slides = slides;
        this.ele = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.ele.classList.add('swiper-slide');
        slides.rapidUpdate();
    }
    ...
    Slide.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
        this.slides.rapidUpdate();
    };
    Slide.decorators = [
        { type: Component, args: [{
                    selector: 'ion-slide',
                    template: '<div class="slide-zoom"><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
                    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
                    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
                },] },
    ];
    Slide.ctorParameters = [
        { type: ElementRef, },
        { type: Slides, decorators: [{ type: Host },] },
    ];
    Slide.propDecorators = {
        'zoom': [{ type: Input },],
    };
    return Slide;
}());
```

This means that you can't use an `ion-slide` without a `ion-slides` parent without getting a template parse error, e.g. in a custom `ion-slide` wrapper such as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myslide',
  template: '<ion-slide> <h1> Test Header </h1> <ng-content></ng-content> </ion-slide>',
})
export class MySlide {
  constructor() {}
}
```

with

```
<ion-slides>
    <myslide> Slide 1 </myslide>
    <myslide> Slide 2 </myslide>
</ion-slides>
```

### Question

I'm trying to modify the ionic slides code to allow a `Slide` without a `Slides` parent by having the `Slides` pass a reference to itself to each child `Slide` after init. I can easily access the `ion-slide` DOM elements that are children of a `Slides` component, but how can I access their angular model?

### What I tried

1) During `Slides` init, I can select the `ion-slides` elements just fine. How can I access the model for these elements? Really, I only need to set the `slides` model variable.

```
Slides.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    // this query works
    var slide_elems = this.getNativeElement().querySelectorAll('ion-slide');

    // this obviously doesn't work because
    // slides needs to be a attribute of the model,
    // not the DOM elem
    slide_elems[0].slides = this;
```

2) @matej-maloča suggested `ViewChild`. Really it looks like I need `ContentChildren`, so I added a `ContentChildren` selector to the `Slides`.

```
Slides.decorators = [
        { type: Component, args: [{
                    selector: 'ion-slides',
                    template: '<div class="swiper-container">' +
                        '<div class="swiper-wrapper">' +
                        '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div [class.hide]="!showPager" class="swiper-pagination"></div>' +
                        '</div>',
                    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
                    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
                    queries: {
                        'ionSlides': new ContentChildren(Slide)
                    },
                },] },
    ];
```

This *almost* works. It selects `Slide` components that are in the content of the `ion-slides` element itself but *not* ones inside a container component (e.g. the custom `myslide`). Is there a way to select those nested `ion-slides` elements as well?

```
<ion-slides>
  <-- selected by ContentChildren -->
  <ion-slide>Slide 1</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>Slide 2</ion-slide>

  <-- the ion-slide within myslide is not selected!! -->
  <myslide>Slide 3</myslide>
</ion-slides>
```

### Notes

I went looking for a link to the source for ion-slides and found [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/slides.ts), which is in typescript. What can I do to update the version I have in my node_modules/ionic-angular to this? Currently everything there is defined in javascript which is a little bit harder to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ViewChild`.

```
// it's variable
@ViewChild('ion-slide') elem: any;
```

In `ngOnInit`:

```
this.elem.nativeElement
```

See docs for further questions: [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child)

If it doesn't work try to get it with ViewChild on life cycle hook `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Okay, trying this out now. It's in javascript so it's a bit wonkier to actually use ViewChild (and I actually need ViewChildren or possibly ContentChildren).

Comment: U also have `ViewChildren` but didn't use it... Try to look for it in docs and `@ViewChild` is typescript decorator so u can't use it js.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. See updated question.

Comment: Okay, I think that you're right that ViewChild, ContentChild, et al are essentially the right solution. They just have limitations that I'm hitting and it doesn't seem quite possible to do what I want.

Comment: I'm sorry that happening. Try to make an issue on angular or ionic GitHub.